# Cannot get callback from service Angular 6

Tags: angularjs, service, callback

Ive created a service with this function

```js
public crearNegocio(negocio,callback){
   var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
   var id_usuario = user.objUser.id_usuario;
   negocio.id_usuario = id_usuario;
   this.http.post(this.config.initialConfig+"/negocio/create/",negocio)
   .subscribe((response)=>{
    callback(null,response)
   },(error)=>{
    callback(error)
   })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

then in a component i call it this way:

```js
import { NegocioService } from '../negocio.service';

constructor(private negocioS:NegocioService) {}

crearNegocio(){
    this.loader=true;
    this.negocioS.crearNegocio(this.negocio,function(err,res){
      if(!err){
        this.loader=false;
        console.log("res",res);
      }else{
        this.loader=false;
        console.log(err)
      }
      
    });
  }
```

It works and inserts into my table, all ok, but when i use the callback to print inside the service function it doesnt do anything, it just skips it, also is the component.

i have de same code on other services and their callbaks work fine.

Comment: where have you defined callback??

Comment: also are you not missing a semicolon? I would suggest you to install VSCode and tslint extension. This can help you catching many such errors

Comment: @CodeNameJack ive defined it in the service, when .i call the function

Comment: can you please add that to the question as well

Comment: @CodeNameJack im using sublime text, i have no space on my macbook to install it, also i have a package for typescript, and it give all errors , also the project compiles.

Comment: I've already added it to the question hehe, in the function crearNegocio(){}

Comment: In your browser, in dev tools, do you see errors getting logged?

Comment: I am asking about the callback method, `callback(null,response)` there should be a method like this

Comment: the callback function is in the crearNegocio() function in the component that i've already post hehe, and also i was printing results, errors and everything but nothing, and the problem is in the service

Comment: I have added an answer, I was missing you callback function as argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it was two issues, one in my Backend with an async.each.

But the other was the "this". It take "this" from the callback so, as it hasn't a variable called loader it wont do anything.

`crearNegocio(){
var self = this;
this.loader=true;;
this.negocioS.crearNegocio(self.negocio,function(err,res){
  if(!err){
    self.loader=false;
  }else{
    self.loader=false;
    console.log(err);
  }

});`

}